# Strange behaviour of helpExtract function from SOfun in R 3.1.2

Tags: r, knitr, helpextract, sofun

I'm using `helpExtract` function from `SOfun` package (written by @Ananda Mahto). The package `SOfun` can be installed from `github` using the following command:

```
devtools::install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")

library(SOfun)
```

The following command gives in the package document works fine.

```
textConnection(
  helpExtract(Function = cor, section = "Examples", type = "s_text")
  )
```

However the same command when using the argument `package=`  fails.

```
textConnection(
  helpExtract(Function = cor, section = "Examples", type = "s_text", package = "stats")
)
```

And throws the follow error message:

```
Error in textConnection(helpExtract(Function = cor, section = "Examples",  : 
  argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string
```

Comment: Why are you using `textConnection` here?

Comment: To include this in `knitr` as child document. As here `\Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(helpExtract(cor, type = "s_code")),
options = list(tidy = FALSE, eval = FALSE))}` for package documentation.

Comment: That error is from `deparse`, but let me see if I can figure anything out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, this is a problem that stems from `deparse`. I don't have time to dig further to explain the error, but the following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
library(SOfun)
x <- helpExtract(Function = cor, section = "Examples", 
                 type = "s_text", package = "stats")
@

\Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(x),
options = list(tidy = FALSE, eval = FALSE))}

\end{document}
```

That is, store the output of `helpExtract` as a variable in a hidden chunk, and use `textConnection` on that variable.